# Couldn't find Product with ID=2 for Product with ID=1 self referential has and belongs to many in Rails 4.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Trying out a simple example with a self-referential `has and belongs to many` and I'm getting "Couldn't find Product with ID=2 for Product with ID=1"

```
def product_params
  # params.fetch(:product, {})
  params.require(:product).permit(hasproducts_attributes: [ :id ])
end
```

My model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many(:hasproducts,
     class_name: "Product",
     join_table: "products_products",
     foreign_key: "first_product_id",
     association_foreign_key: "second_product_id")

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hasproducts
end
```

My controller:

```
def update  
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update(product_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I don't get it... Am I not supplying enough information for the update to take place?

Request

Parameters:

```
{
   "utf8" => "✓",
   "_method" => "patch",
   "authenticity_token" => "something",
   "product" => { "hasproducts_attributes" => { "0" => { "id" => "2" }}},
   "commit" => "Update Product",
   "id" => "1"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `params.require(:product).permit(hasproduct_ids: [])`? And passing just an array of ids